# show hide div in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have this code:

```
class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            resetPass:true
        };
    }

resetPassword(resetPass) {
    if(resetPass) {
        this.setState ({

        })
    }
}

<div style={{display:`${this.state.resetPass === true ? "none":"block"}`}}>
    test 1
</div>


<div style={{display:`${this.state.resetPass === true ? "block" : "none" }`}}>
    test2
</div>
```

so i created a button like this

```
<button onClick = {this.resetPassword(resetPass)} >testing</button>
```

i want to write a function that show the hidden div and hide the current div in react?? any idea how it works??
thanks in advance

Comment: update your code like `this.resetPassword.bind(this,resetPass)` and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        resetPass: true
    }
}

resetPassword = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ resetPass: !prevState.resetPass }));
}

<button onClick = {this.resetPassword} >testing</button>
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/236603/)

Comment: it works but only on doubleclick i want it on click any idea what is the problem?

Comment: @eddy, I have updated the code. Should work now perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
resetPassword() {
  this.setState ({resetPass:this.state.resetPass?false:true})
}

{this.state.resetPass?<div>test1</div>:<div>test2</div>}

<button onClick = {this.resetPassword} > testing</button>
```

This'll work for you.

Comment: <button onClick = {this.resetPassword()} > testing</button>
should not pass a function call in the click event handler.  `this.resetPassword()`

Answer (score 0):

```
resetPassword=()=>{

 if(this.state.resetPass) {

   this.setState ({

    })

    }
}
```

`<button onClick = {this.resetPassword} > testing</button>`

Comment: Hi! A code snippet alone is in most cases not considered to be a quality answer. It would be great if you could add some words of explanation about how and why this code provides an answer to the question.

Answer (score -1):

resetPassword function returns nothing, so `this.resetPassword(resetPass)`equals to undefined, so `onClick = {this.resetPassword(resetPass)}`equals onClick = {undefined}. 'bind' function allows you to pass parameter without calling the fuction and it returns a new function.

```
onClick = {this.resetPassword.bind(this, resetPass)}
```

This returns a new function every time when it is called, so it can cause some performance issues.

Instead 'bind' you can also use this.

```
onClick = {() => {this.resetPassword(this, resetPass);}}
```

Comment: onClick = {this.resetPassword.bind(this.resetPass)}, `this.resetPass` would be undefined.

Comment: Oh god, I made a syntax error. it should be  {this.resetPassword(this, resetPass);}}. By the way thanks for noticing my mistake.